Python312\python -OO setup.py build_exe throws Return code: 3221225477
In my setup_base.py script, when I import wx and run:
Python312\\python -OO setup.py build_exe

I am getting an exit code of 3221225477. When I remove the import wx, it succeeds with an exit code of 0.
My setup configuration is as follows:

Python3.12
cx-freeze 7.1.0.post0
wxpython 4.2.1.

I'm wondering if there are any compatible libraries or a different way to handle this so that I don't get the exit code when importing wx in setup_base.py.
